# Python Script optimization

Tags: python, numba, jit

I can't optimize the code. The maximum optimization was from 20 seconds to 4 (with 20 million items in the value list). I don't know how to do it even faster, the analyze method is working very slowly. What are the ways? Data caching or some kind of cleaning that does not affect the output. If I'm not mistaken, then over time the memory goes to the ceiling, but I didn't check it.
Is it possible to speed up here when using numba? If so, how?

## client.py

```
import socket
import struct
import threading
import time


from scipy import stats


class Client:
    def __init__(self, mcast_grp, mcast_port):
        self.package_count = 0
        self.lose_package_count = 1
        self.package = []
        self.package_sum = 0
        self.socket = self.create_socket(mcast_grp, mcast_port)

    def create_socket(self, mcast_grp, mcast_port):
        """ Создание сокета для сбора статистики """
        sock = socket.socket(
            socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP
        )
        sock.setsockopt(
            socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1
        )
        sock.bind(('', mcast_port))
        mreq = struct.pack(
            "4sl", socket.inet_aton(mcast_grp), socket.INADDR_ANY
        )
        sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)
        return sock

    def accept(self):
        """ """
        prev_number = 1
        while True:
            try:
                response = self.socket.recv(10240).decode().split(':')
                self.package.append(float(response[1]))
                self.lose_package_count += (int(response[0]) - prev_number) - 1
                self.package_count += 1
                self.package_sum += float(response[1])
                prev_number = int(response[0])
            except:
                continue

    def analyze(self):
        """ Вечный цикл запрашивающий вывод статистики """
        while True:
            _ = input('Для вывода статистики нажмите "enter"')
            start = time.time()
            print(
                f'Количество пакетов: {self.package_count}\n'
                f'Потеряно пакетов: {self.lose_package_count}\n'
                f'Среднее арифметическое: {self.package_sum / self.package_count}\n'
                f'Стандартное отконение: {stats.gstd(self.package)}\n'
                f'Мода: {stats.mode(self.package)}\n'
                f'Время обработки данных: {time.time() - start}\n'
            )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = Client('224.1.1.1', 5004)
    threading.Thread(target=client.accept).start()
    threading.Thread(target=client.analyze).start()
```

## server.py

```
import random
import socket

import yaml


class Server:
    def __init__(self,
                 group,
                 port,
                 ttl):
        self.group = group
        self.port = port
        self.socket = self.create_socket(ttl)

def create_socket(self, ttl):
    """ Создание сокета для отправки сообщений """
    sock = socket.socket(
        socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP
    )
    sock.setsockopt(
        socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, ttl
    )
    return sock

def send(self, min_range, max_range):
    """ Отправка пакетов """
    package_count = 1
    while True:
        try:
            message = (f'{package_count}:'
                      f'{random.randint(min_range, max_range)}')
            self.socket.sendto(
                bytes(message, encoding='utf-8'), (self.group, self.port)
            )
            package_count += 1
        except:
            continue

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('config.yaml', 'r') as config:
        config = yaml.load(config, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
        multi_group = config['multi_group']
        ran_range = config['range']
    server = Server(
        group=multi_group['group'],
        port=multi_group['port'],
        ttl=multi_group['ttl']
    )
    server.send(min_range=ran_range['min'], max_range=ran_range['max'])
```

## config.yaml

```
range:
  min: 1
  max: 10
multi_group:
  group: 224.1.1.1
  port: 5004
  ttl: 2
```

Comment: It would be useful if you stated briefly what you are trying to do. I presume your `analyze()` method is just monitoring performance and not doing the intended actual processing - if so, it competes heavily with the `accept()` method and Python isn't really very multi-threaded. If it is just monitoring, try adding a `sleep(0.2)` inside the loop.

Comment: Your code is very simply optimised, including the memory consumption, if the code is actually representative of whatever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I wrote it from the beginning. I got rid of the list and made calculations when receiving the package. Thus, I got rid of lengthy calculations (now they are recalculated every time and not calculated again) and from using additional memory. Computational functions decorated with jit(fastmath=True, forceobj=True)

Answer (score 2):

No there is **no chance to optimize this using Numba** because Numba does not support network functions yet (and will not support it soon). Moreover, it only barely support string and `bytes` functions and the supported operations are significantly slower than CPython so far. In fact, Numba is meant to optimize numerical compute-bound codes and clearly not network-based ones. **Cython** may help but do not expect a significant speed up. Networking system calls and the use of Python are more likely to be the source of the possible slowdown.

Comment: It turns out that this is not optimized in any way?

Comment: For Numba, not even a chance. Numba will report a warning/error and use a fallback CPython implementation. The resulting code should be as fast than CPython if not slower due to the Numba attempt to compile the function (which will definitively fail on such code unless you succeed to isolate the computational part which will be slower with Numba anyway).

Comment: And if we somehow separate the part of data collection and the part of mathematical calculations?

Comment: Then Numba could compile the function but calling a Numba function takes some time (eg at least 200 ns on my machine per call) and your code is not compute-bound enough so to get faster results. Cython could speed up this but the gain will likely be small (one have to test to be sure). Networking function are certainly what takes the most time in your code, and otherwise it it certainly decoding functions. For example: `self.socket.recv(10240).decode().split(':')`. Using a native C/C++ code can significantly speed up this part if networking functions are not the bottleneck.